# How can i style a sentences first word with only css

Tags: html, css

```
<h2>hello world</h2>
```

Here, i want to styling first word "hello" without using any span or b tag or any JavaScript. just using style like `h2:first-word{color:red}`.

Is it possible? If possible how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because there's no `:first-word` selector, only `:first-letter` and `:first-line`. You'll need insert span dynamically with JS if you don't control original HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know it is not possible with pure css.
There are some solutions with javascript.

Library: [nthEverything](https://github.com/FWeinb/nthEverything)
Examples: [Examples with ::first-word](https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/)